# How to match criteria within object?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm having a Meteor chat application and try to delete all chats when a user removes the friendship. At the moment, I'm using this:

```
Friends.before.remove(function (userId, doc) {
// Delete Chats


Chats.find({users: {$elemMatch: {id: doc.user1, id: doc.user2}}}).forEach(function (docx) {

    Chats.remove(docx._id);
})
});
```

Problem here: This code deletes ALL chats of a user, and not only the one where the match is correct. My chat document has a structure like this:

Chat

```
created_at: Date
users: [ {id: 'abc'}, {id: 'def'}]
last_message: Date
```

How can I remove all chats, that have both users in their arrays?

Answer (score 1):

Use $all operator instead of $elemMatch.

> ### $all
>
> The $all operator selects the documents where the value of a field is an array that contains all the specified elements. To specify an $all expression, use the following prototype:

```
{ <field>: { $all: [ <value1> , <value2> ... ] } }
```

[See MongoDB Docs.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/)